# How to be equal to all keyCodes

Tags: cocoa, swift3

I would like for the event.keyCode to be equal to all the keyCodes 
but right now i can only make it be equal to one shown below

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {

    if event.keyCode == 1 {
        textField1.stringValue = "anything"
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to do something on every key down, simply don't check the key code at all:

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    textField1.stringValue = "anything"
}
```